# How to go about breaking table content across multiple lines?

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I'm trying to make a list of skills for my CV, and I've been trying every which way to get some things to break across multiple lines, to no avail. It just looks like crap.

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{rSection}{Skills}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
BSL 2 Aseptic \& Sterile Technique & Polyacrylamide \& Agarose Gel Electrophoresis \\
Cell Culture & SDS-PAGE \\
Streak \& Spread Plating & Western Blotting \\
Light \& Phase-Contrast Microscopy & Chromatography: Column, Thin-Layer, Gas\\
Polymerase Chain Reaction (PCR) & Protein Isolation/Quantification/Crystallization\\
Restriction Enzyme Digests & Spectrophotometry: Bradford Protein Assay, Lowry Protein Assay, Edelhoch Protein Assay\\
Gram Staining Techniques & Gene Expression Analysis\\
Gene Cloning and Transformation & Coliform Testing (Edvotek, Phenol Red Lactose, Endo-Agar)\\
DNA construct design & Microbial Biochemical characterization (IMViC, Enterotube II, Oxi/Ferm Tube II, Api 20NE, API 20E)\\
DNA & Plasmid Isolation & Spectroscopy: IR \textsuperscript{1}H NMR, Fluorescence\\
Phage P1 Transduction & Chromatography: Column, Thin-Layer, Gas\\
Plaque Assay & Y\\
Antibiotic assay (MIC) & Y\\
Conjugation-based Transformation & Y\\
Plant Single Cell Isolation & Y\\
Plant Tissue Culture & Y\\
\end{tabular}
\label{default}
\end{table}%


\end{rSection}
```

I appreciate the help guys. I would also love it if you could explain what to do in this situation, so I know what to do in the future! I hate to just come here and ask questions upon questions.

Comment: You should use `longtable`. Anyway, I don't think a table should float in a cv.

Comment: Isn't a `itemize` or `enumerate` list (with adapted labels) better suited for this?

Comment: Hm. I hadn't really thought about that, I just assumed that it would be simpler to have a table with two columns to list my skills. Thanks guys, I'll do an itemize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an itemized list as suggested above but if you have a block of text in your table you may be better off creating a paragraph column in your table. You can set things up using the tabular environment:

```
\begin{tabular}{cp{5.0cm}c}
```

where the p{*width*} creates a vertically top aligned paragraph.

There are some problems with the slashes you have in your text. With the way you are doing it, i.e., Protein Isolation/Quantification/Crystallization, LaTeX sees this as one word and does not know how to break them. So it doesn't. You will have to add the \slash{} macro so it looks something like:

Protein Isolation\slash{} Quantification\slash{} Crystallization

This should allow LaTeX to typeset things properly. I could not get your MWE to run but your tabular code should look like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{cp{5.0cm}c}
BSL 2 Aseptic \& Sterile Technique & Polyacrylamide \& Agarose Gel Electrophoresis \\
Cell Culture & SDS-PAGE \\
Streak \& Spread Plating & Western Blotting \\
Light \& Phase-Contrast Microscopy & Chromatography: Column, Thin-Layer, Gas\\
Polymerase Chain Reaction (PCR) & Protein Isolation\slash{} Quantification\slash{} Crystallization\\
Restriction Enzyme Digests & Spectrophotometry: Bradford Protein Assay, Lowry Protein Assay, Edelhoch Protein Assay\\
Gram Staining Techniques & Gene Expression Analysis\\
Gene Cloning and Transformation & Coliform Testing (Edvotek, Phenol Red Lactose, Endo-Agar)\\
DNA construct design & Microbial Biochemical characterization (IMViC, Enterotube II, Oxi\slash{} Ferm Tube II, Api 20NE, API 20E)\\
DNA & Plasmid Isolation & Spectroscopy: IR \textsuperscript{1}H NMR, Fluorescence\\
Phage P1 Transduction & Chromatography: Column, Thin-Layer, Gas\\
Plaque Assay & Y\\
Antibiotic assay (MIC) & Y\\
Conjugation-based Transformation & Y\\
Plant Single Cell Isolation & Y\\
Plant Tissue Culture & Y\\
\end{tabular}
```

This should give you the breaks you are looking for.

Comment: Cool, thank you! I had no idea that the \ would count it as one word. So this is a LaTeX wide thing? Each time, I'd have to do \slash{}?

Comment: I tend to use \slash{} instead of \ because I don't know where the breaks are going to be.

Answer (score 1):

Use package `tabularx` and then:

```
 \noindent      
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{5cm}Xp{5cm} @{}}
            BSL 2 Aseptic \& Sterile Technique & Polyacrylamide \& Agarose Gel 
            Electrophoresis \\
            Cell Culture & SDS-PAGE \\
            Streak \& Spread Plating & Western Blotting \\
            Light \& Phase-Contrast Microscopy & Chromatography: Column, Thin-Layer, 
            Gas\\
            Polymerase Chain Reaction (PCR) & Protein 
            Isolation/Quantification/Crystallization\\
            Restriction Enzyme Digests & Spectrophotometry: Bradford Protein Assay, 
            Lowry Protein Assay, Edelhoch Protein Assay\\
            Gram Staining Techniques & Gene Expression Analysis\\
            Gene Cloning and Transformation & Coliform Testing (Edvotek, Phenol Red 
            Lactose, Endo-Agar)\\
            DNA construct design & Microbial Biochemical characterization (IMViC, 
            Enterotube II, Oxi/Ferm Tube II, Api 20NE, API 20E)\\
            DNA & Plasmid Isolation & Spectroscopy: IR \textsuperscript{1}H NMR, 
            Fluorescence\\
            Phage P1 Transduction & Chromatography: Column, Thin-Layer, Gas\\
            Plaque Assay & Y\\
            Antibiotic assay (MIC) & Y\\
            Conjugation-based Transformation & Y\\
            Plant Single Cell Isolation & Y\\
            Plant Tissue Culture & Y\\
 \end{tabularx}
```

However, using a `table` environment in a resume makes no sense, there is nothing to float.

Comment: Thanks Herbert, I actually just made two mini pages with an \itemize, and it worked out beautifully. Thanks for the help though!